# Testing jar files in FitNesse

Tags: java, jar, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm using FitNesse for the first time and I'm not sure I understand how I should use it for acceptance testing...

So the first question is whether it is possible to somehow run test on the whole program (eg. on a .jar file) or run the main() method of the application and get the results from the command line.

If the answer yes: is this a bad idea? :D If I understand correctly, acceptance tests should verify if the requirements of a specification are met, but I haven't found any example which would show how to test a complete software in FitNesse. Moreover, every tutorial I saw describes a small test on a trivial example (even the two-minute-tutorial on fitnesse.org) which to me looks like a unit test.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are trying to tests: is it a command line interface (as you are asking about a `main()`), a web application, a service, or ...

Answer (score 1):

FitNesse by itself is just a test runner and an editor to maintain test definitions (using a wiki). Its goal is to have test definitions (and results) that are understandable (and even writable) for non-programmers so a wider audience can contribute.

How and what you use it for is up to you. You have to define the glue code (aka fixtures) that couple the test definitions to the system you are testing. And then write the tests to verify what you want to check (at the right level of abstraction).

You could use it to define and run unit tests, but indeed that is not what it intended for (just like you can use jUnit to run acceptance tests). It is intended to test from a functional point of view to verify the acceptance criteria are met. These tend to be at a higher level of abstraction than the behaviour of a class or method.

I generally do not use FitNesse to start the program/system I'm testing, but to verify its behaviour once it is running. For instance with a web shop I would verify I can see the items in the catalogue, place them in a shopping basket, see correct total price and purchase.
But FitNesse itself cannot immediately do this. You need to write code that allows the wiki to interact with a browser and perform the clicks and checks needed.

Some standard plugins exist to make this connection for REST or SOAP services, browsers, databases, etc

I myself maintain [such a plugin that combines FitNesse with Selenium and some other libraries](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) so one can start testing websites, services (and command line applications) right away without the need to write custom code. But it does not start the systems to be tested: you have to take care of that yourself (you could be starting docker containers, run from command line or use some intricate tool to deploy to a remote test server).

Even using my project the actual test definitions are up to you. So your test could just be that when you click a checkbox it becomes checked. But it could also be a complete customer journey from arriving at the site, browsing, payment process to final order state in some warehouse management application.

FitNesse does help support composition of small test steps to actions at a higher level of abstraction, purely in the test domain (without the need to program in Java, C# ...), using 'scenarios'. So one can define a scenario that encapsulates the actions needed to log in, another to place an order and combine these to make a scenario that checks an item can be bought and the correct price is charged. This scenario can then be used to test various items may be bought and their correct price is charged (which is what I would call an acceptance test).

Using my project you get the basic steps to do stuff like open a website with a browser, click on a button, check a value, call a REST service, check an XML response. You can then use FitNesse to compose these steps to create the tests that you want.